# Form isn't shown

Tags: php

I have a file test.php with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Listing 10.2 </title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

<form method="post" action="test.php" >
    <p> <input type="text" name="guess"/> </p>
</form>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['guess'] )) {
    print "Last guess $_POST['guess']";
}
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a problem with the form not showing up.  However, if I remove the PHP portion of the code, it is visible. What is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed the $_POST variable into the string like that, trying changing the php section to:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['guess'] )) {
    print "Last guess {$_POST['guess']}";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Why is $_POST a special case? If i put in some random variable it will be printed out normally.

Comment: Specifically, it's not the $_POST that causes the problem, it's the associative array. The square bracket is not a valid character to be used in a variable name, so the simple string parsing stops at that point. You have to use the "complex" syntax for embedding arrays in strings.

Comment: One thing you should also look at is your PHP error-reporting settings. Your problem isn't that the form wasn't being displayed, but that the page was crashing due to a PHP syntax error. You should make sure that you have some way to view those errors, or you'll have a very hard time debugging.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. How do I set up the error reporting? I allready have error_reporting= E_ALL set in php.ini file, but it doesn't shows these kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use . for combine values and strings

```
if(!empty($_POST['guess'] ))
{
    echo "Last guess".$_POST['guess'];
}
```